# How to have a distributed parameter?

Tags: java, authentication

At the moment I'm making a POST call to an authentication service from a server part of a cluster of servers, and when I get the response with the authentication token, I save that token in the memory of the app in that server. But when the next call comes in and I try using the same token, there's no guarantee that I'm in the same server that has the token or if I'm in a different one inside the cluster, and so the call fails because there's no token.

Any idea of how I can save that token so that all servers can use the same token without invalidating the other servers?

Thanks

Comment: Either the all nodes need to have access to the token or the request has to go to the same node for all requests in the session

Comment: @MiserableVariable yup, that's fundamentally how it must work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing the key in-process in a single server's memory, use something shared like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) – or just use a regular ol' database.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making all the calls sequencial inside the same server, so all calls have the same token... Thanks